# For data sharing either Provider or Local Storage should I select

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, inject

I would like to use `Providers` for data sharing due to the slowness of `LocalStorage`. So could you tell me will I have to face any issues due to this approach inside the Ionic 3 mobile apps?

*Note:* Provider is `singleton`

*Declare it like this:*

*project.ts*

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectProvider {

project: Project

constructor((){}

}
```

Use when I need it on any other page:

*home.ts*

```
constructor(private projectProvider: ProjectProvider){} 

    ionViewDidEnter() {
       this.projectProvider.project = val;//after this I can use this anywhere
    }
```

I have used above approach instead of this:

```
 const project: Project = await this.storage.get('project');
```

Here you can see that I have to wait till it retrieves. That is a problem with my app since my client needs to develop an app almost without loader icon on the pages. So will I have to face any issues on this approach?

Comment: Why don't you use promise on your Storage call? And you use SQLLite instead localstorage, right?

Comment: This pattern I really like since I came from `C#` world :). and my use case where I need that data immediately for use. @Pterrat Yes `SQLLite`.

Comment: Ok, I think your code is correct. and you will not have any issues. May be you could improve your ProjetProvider about initing project value

Comment: I implemented the exact same pattern today and i'm also aware of any unexpected problems. The performance of localstorage was too poor even with the promises.

Answer (score 0):

If the user will refresh the page (pushing the page down will refresh) the provider will lose the data, you can use providers as singleton but they aren't good for persistent data. Use providers for sharing data between components.

Comment: There is no way to refresh the page on my app. No, pull to refresh. I have used provider as Singleton too. Now, what are your thoughts? Still, this is not good? since my use case is different. I don't like to use loading icon on the pages. (i.e. I like. But my client doesn't :D)

Comment: You can preload from local storage and put it on a provider, a sort of "cache".

Comment: Hope you didn't understand my use case. I don't like to wait till data coming from cache or local storage. So what are the options which I have then? Thanks for your feedback.